# How to get Public streams statuses/firehose permission from twitter?

Tags: twitter-streaming-api

I am looking  for getting public status of users in twitter but while searching this api. I have not found any thing in documentation to get permission.

This endpoint requires special permission to access.

Returns all public statuses. Few applications require this level of access. Creative use of a combination of other resources and various access levels can satisfy nearly every application use case.
Resource URL
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/firehose.json

please checkout api here 
https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/firehose

Comment: `firehose` is only available through GNIP and Enterprise Subscription to Twitter API endpoints. They recently launched a 'Premium Subscription', but what will be made available under it is still unclear except for a few obvious ones.